# Using compareProposalResponseResults SDK class to verify endorsed transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to understand why a verification of endorsed transactions has been positioned at the application layer instead of Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 ledger network.

Let's assume three possible scenarios :

a) Using Oracles to request information needed to perform a function, and that the address to the Oracle is embedded into transaction attribute.

b) Execution of different actions depending on the origin of the transaction (i.e. through the unmarshalled peer or sender identity)

c) Original smart contract code is tampered with through an injection of malicious binary code into the dev-* container

If, let's say, a genuine network participant with malicious intents wants to inject some garbage into the ledger and has an access to the application source code, she/he can tweak around this SDK function in order to force proposed transactions with dissimilar results to be sent straight to Orderers. If I understand right, the network will not detect such a misconduct.

Please correct me if I am wrong and if this issue can somehow be mitigated at the network layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application layer is the one to fulfill the endorsement policy, since the application to invoke the chaincode, therefore to make it valid the application has to go and literally invoke chaincode against all parties involved or related to given transaction.

That being said, it become kind of obvious that once application at any case to invoke and collect endorsements it's make many sense to have the application layer to verify endorsement results and make sure they are correct before submitting to the ordering service.

However if client won't do that check or will try to temper the endorsement results, first of all it won't be able to provide required signatures over tampered data. While moreover there is a VSCC (Validation System Chaincode) which takes care to validate transaction to ensure that endorsement policy satisfied, overwise rejects/invalidates the transaction.

I'd say doing verification on the application side is more like a best practices and the optimization path which aims to spare validation cycles for transaction known not to be consistent once application receives all endorsement results.